# mysql: [ERROR] unknown variable 'pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid'

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-22.04

I am new to mysql and coding in general and would like to use mysql to create a database for a project. I tried installing it on my computer, I am using WSL1 running ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. After installing using `sudo apt install mysql-server`
I wanted to check the version using `mysql --version` and the following error ocurred:

`mysql: [ERROR] unknown variable 'pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid'.`

I have also tried starting mysql with `sudo service mysql start` and I get the following warning:

`su: warning: cannot change directory to /nonexistent: No such file or directory`

I haven't been able to use mysql and do not have access to the console. I haven't yet found a clear solution on other sites so I am asking here.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271400/unknown-variable-pid-file-run-mysqld-mysqld-pid-when-setting-50-server-cnf

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to desintall mysql and purge ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This reads more like a comment than an answer to me: One of the primary purposes of the question's comment section is to ask for clarification or more details from the asker.